# req.isAuthenticated won't work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have built a mini CMS system using Node Js, Express, Mongoose and Passport.js.
When the client is loging out, I get this error in the console: `'Cannot read property 'id' of null'`, the error comes from the `PrivateThread.find().lean().then()...`

```
// Pass User Data To Template
function sendUserData(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, doNotSend).then(user => {
      switch(true) {
        case user.banned:
          req.logOut();
          flashRedirect(req, res, '/login', 'res-err', 'Some message');
          break;

        case !user.activated:
          req.logOut();
          flashRedirect(req, res, '/login', 'res-err', 'Somem message');
          break;

        default:
          res.locals.foundUser = user;
          PrivateThread.find({ participants: req.user.id }).lean().then(foundThreads => {
            let notifications = foundThreads.filter(thread => !thread.readBy.toString().includes(req.user.id));
            res.locals.notifications = notifications.length;
          });
          next();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => res.send(err));
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

This is the logout route:

```
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

I'm only getting the error when the client is loging out through the logout page.

Comment: try logging `req` and see if `user` is present in it

Comment: I moved the next() to PrivateThred.find()... block and I'm not getting the error anymore